# ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index | Pandas DataFrame.unique()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I am trying to get a new dataset, or change the value of the current dataset columns to their unique values.
Here is an example of what I am trying to get :

```
   A B
 -----
0| 1 1
1| 2 5
2| 1 5
3| 7 9
4| 7 9
5| 8 9

Wanted Result    Not Wanted Result
       A B              A B
     -----             -----
    0| 1 1           0| 1 1
    1| 2 5           1| 2 5
    2| 7 9           2| 
    3| 8             3| 7 9
                     4|
                     5| 8
```

I don't really care about the index but it seems to be the problem.
My code so far is pretty simple, I tried 2 approaches, 1 with a new dataFrame and one without.

```py
#With New DataFrame
def UniqueResults(dataframe):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for col in dataframe:
        S=pd.Series(dataframe[col].unique())
        df[col]=S.values
    return df

#Without new DataFrame
def UniqueResults(dataframe):
    for col in dataframe:
        dataframe[col]=dataframe[col].unique()
    return dataframe
```

Both times, I get the error:

```
Length of Values does not match length of index
```

Answer (score 141, accepted):

The error comes up when you are trying to assign a list of numpy array of different length to a data frame, and it can be reproduced as follows:

A data frame of four rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4]})
```

Now trying to assign a list/array of two elements to it:

```
df['B'] = [3,4]   # or df['B'] = np.array([3,4])
```

Both errors out:

> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Because the data frame has four rows but the list and array has only two elements.

***Work around Solution*** (use with caution): convert the list/array to a pandas Series, and then when you do assignment, missing index in the Series will be filled with *NaN*:

```
df['B'] = pd.Series([3,4])

df
#   A     B
#0  1   3.0
#1  2   4.0
#2  3   NaN          # NaN because the value at index 2 and 3 doesn't exist in the Series
#3  4   NaN
```

---

For your specific problem, if you don't care about the index or the correspondence of values between columns, you can reset index for each column after dropping the duplicates:

```
df.apply(lambda col: col.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True))

#   A     B
#0  1   1.0
#1  2   5.0
#2  7   9.0
#3  8   NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to get around this issue is to keep the unique values in a list and use `itertools.zip_longest` to transpose the data and pass it into the DataFrame constructor:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def UniqueResults(dataframe):
    tmp = [dataframe[col].unique() for col in dataframe]
    return pd.DataFrame(zip_longest(*tmp), columns=dataframe.columns)

out = UniqueResults(df)
```

Output:

```
   A    B
0  1  1.0
1  2  5.0
2  7  9.0
3  8  NaN
```

At least for small DataFrames, this seems to be faster (for example on OP's sample):

```
%timeit out = df.apply(lambda col: col.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True))
1.27 ms ± 50.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit x = UniqueResults(df)
426 µs ± 24.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution is to make the solution suggested by OP into a working one. We just need to cast the unique values of each column into a pandas Series:

```py
df1 = df.apply(lambda col: pd.Series(col.unique()))
df1
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

you can chage your code by
`

```
def UniqueResults(dataframe):
   df = pd.DataFrame()
   for col in dataframe:
       S=dataframe[col].unique()
       df=pd.concat([df,S],axis=1)
   df.columns=dataframe.columns
   return df
```

`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).