# Iterating over the rows of two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes let's call first one df and the second one compare_df: 
First one is like this:

```
Date         cell         tumor_size (assume it is three dimensional)
25/10/2015    113           [51, 52, 55]
22/10/2015    222           [50, 68, 22]
22/10/2015    883           [45, 23, 67]
20/10/2015    334           [35, 23, 76]
```

and second one is like that:

```
Date         cell         tumor_size
19/10/2015    564           [47, 23, 56]
19/10/2015    123           [56, 11, 23]
22/10/2014    345           [36, 66, 78]
13/12/2013    456           [44, 21, 83]
```

For each row in the dataframe I want to go through each row in the second dataframe and record the euclidean distances then get the minimum one. This is my code tries to accomplish this:

```
# These will be our lists of pairs and size differences.
pairs = []
diffs = []


for row in df.itertuples():
     compare_df['distance'] = np.linalg.norm(compare_df.tumor_size - row.tumor_size) # I get error for this line
     row_of_interest = compare_df.loc[compare_df.distance == compare_df.distance.min()]
     pairs.append(row_of_interest.cell.values[0])
     diffs.append(row_of_interest.distance.values[0])

df['most_similar_to'] = pairs
df['similarity'] = diffs
```

However I get:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Although size of the vectors are the same, and I drop `Nan` values. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42382263/valueerror-length-of-values-does-not-match-length-of-index-pandas-dataframe-u

Comment: It is not a dublicate because I checked the size of vectors. There is something wrong with my code itself but I don't know what

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: and is `row.tumor_size` an `np.array` or just `list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in trying to subtract a `pd.Series` of large size (`compare_df.tumor_size`) from a `list` of size three (`row.tumor_size`). When subtracting `list`/`tuple` from `pd.Series`, `pandas` tries to match both sequences and subtract each two matching rows. However, when the `list` and the `pd.Series` are of different size, it doesn't know how to match, and raises the exception.

Judging from the error code, your `pandas` version is probably a bit old. You can try to use `apply` to force the subtraction operator to be used row by row:

```
compare_df.tumor_size.apply(
    lambda compare_size: np.array(compare_size) - np.array(row.tumor_size)
)
```

Of course, it may be beneficial to convert all list to `np.array` ahead of time.

If you don't like `np.array`, you can use:

```
compare_df.tumor_size.apply(
    lambda compare_size: [compare_size[i] - row.tumor_size[i] for i in range(3)]
)
```

---

**In `pandas 0.21.0`** (perhaps a bit earlier), you would have got a different error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

In this case, there is an easier solution - just convert the list to an `np.array`, and it will work like magic

```
compare_df.tumor_size -  np.array(row.tumor_size)
```

For me, this work with `pandas==0.21.0` and `numpy==1.13.3`.