# Plot asymmetric error bars in different colors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data frame in pandas and I would like to plot the error bars in different colors (The colors are given in a column 'Colors').

I'm using the [errorbar function](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html) in matplotlib and my code works if the error is symmetric.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show, subplots

import numpy as np  

# Definition of the dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame({'Colors': {0: 'Red', 1: 'Blue', 2: 'Green', 3: 'Blue'}, 'X_values': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}, 'Y_values': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 8, 3: 10}, 'MinY_values': {0: 1.5, 1: 3, 2: 7.5, 3: 8}, 'MaxY_values': {0: 2.5, 1: 5, 2: 9.5, 3: 11}})



# Definition of the different colors

color = []
 

for i in df['Colors']:
    if i == 'Red':
        color.append('red')
    if i == 'Blue':
        color.append('blue')
    if i == 'Green':
        color.append('green')   
        
# Figure

fig,axes = subplots(2,1,sharex = True)

for x_val,y_val,min_val,max_val,colors in zip(df['X_values'],df['Y_values'],df['MinY_values'],df['MaxY_values'],color):
    axes[0].errorbar(x_val,y_val,yerr = max_val,color = colors,barsabove='True',fmt = '+')
    
for x_val,y_val,min_val,max_val,colors in zip(df['X_values'],df['Y_values'],df['MinY_values'],df['MaxY_values'],color):
    axes[1].errorbar(x_val,y_val,yerr = max_val,color = colors,barsabove='True',fmt = '+')
    
show()
```

It returns the following plot:

[image: Plot]

Now, I have asymmetric errors, then in the `errorbar` function, `yerr` should be define as `yerr = [min_val,max_val]` using the same names in the precedent code. (There is an example on how to get asymmetric errors [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/errorbar_features.html))

When I do that, the following error appears:

```
ValueError: The lengths of the data (1) and the error 2 do not match
```

I read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42382263/valueerror-length-of-values-does-not-match-length-of-index-pandas-dataframe-u/42382321), but there is the same number of elements in all my data frame columns (4).

What can I do to have the same plot below but with the asymmetric errors ?

Here is my complete code with issue:

```
import pandas as pd

from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show, subplots

import numpy as np  

# Definition of the dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame({'Colors': {0: 'Red', 1: 'Blue', 2: 'Green', 3: 'Blue'}, 'X_values': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}, 'Y_values': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 8, 3: 10}, 'MinY_values': {0: 1.5, 1: 3, 2: 7.5, 3: 8}, 'MaxY_values': {0: 2.5, 1: 5, 2: 9.5, 3: 11}})



# Definition of the different colors

color = []
 

for i in df['Colors']:
    if i == 'Red':
        color.append('red')
    if i == 'Blue':
        color.append('blue')
    if i == 'Green':
        color.append('green')   
        
# Figure

fig,axes = subplots(2,1,sharex = True)

for x_val,y_val,min_val,max_val,colors in zip(df['X_values'],df['Y_values'],df['MinY_values'],df['MaxY_values'],color):
    axes[0].errorbar(x_val,y_val,yerr = [min_val,max_val] ,color = colors,barsabove='True',fmt = '+')
    
for x_val,y_val,min_val,max_val,colors in zip(df['X_values'],df['Y_values'],df['MinY_values'],df['MaxY_values'],color):
    axes[1].errorbar(x_val,y_val,yerr = [min_val,max_val] ,color = colors,barsabove='True',fmt = '+')
    
show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because you are plotting length-1 data and errors. First, let's see the [doc string](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html):

> `xerr`, `yerr`  float or array-like, shape(N,) or shape(2, N), optional
>
> The errorbar sizes:
>
> - scalar: Symmetric +/- values for all data points.
> - shape(N,): Symmetric +/-values for each data point.
> - shape(2, N): Separate - and + values for each bar. First row contains the lower errors, the second row contains the upper errors.
> - None: No errorbar.

When you give `yerr = [min_val, max_val]`, it is interpreted as a shape(N,) array - which as you can see, it then thinks are symmetric values for each point. But since you only have one data point (`N=1`), it gets confused.

Instead, you want to give your errors as a shape(2, N) list or array. For example:

```py
yerr=[[min_val], [max_val]]
```

Which looks like this in one of your calls to `errorbar`:

```py
for x_val, y_val, min_val, max_val, colors in zip(df['X_values'], df['Y_values'], df['MinY_values'], df['MaxY_values'], color):
    axes[0].errorbar(x_val, y_val, yerr=[[min_val], [max_val]], color=colors, barsabove='True', fmt='+')
```

[image]